# Payment gateway integration

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I would like to add a payment module on my website that I`m going to build, I want the users to pay mainly using Credit Cards, Master Cards or Visas. It would be good to also add PayPal payment, any other method will be acceptable.

If there are tutorials for the installation of the module would be great.

PS: I don`t mind paying for the usage of the service.

Answer (score 1):

All the major merchants (PayPal, Google Checkout, Authorize.Net, etc.) will have integration capabilities with PHP. For example, here's some [sample code](https://developer.authorize.net/downloads/samplecode/) for Authorize.Net.

Comment: @sikas You would use a payment provider like Sage Pay or HSBC to take credit/debit card payments. RTFM.

Comment: @sikas: I believe with Authorize.Net you can select which type of cards you would allow. Their says the support all major cards:

http://www.fuzeqna.com/authorize.net/consumer/kbdetail.asp?kbid=19&SearchType=standard&referrer=&gpn=&CustID=&bUseEditor=&keyword=Mastercard&rfield=&usertype=&gpv=&formaction=search&catID1=&IncludeHTML=&TotalResults=461&submitbutton=Go&match=and

Answer (score 1):

Most payment gateway providers provide developers with documentation on how to integrate their gateways in a plethora of languages such as PHP, Java, .NET etc.